# Store setup with simpleWebRTC

Tags: reactjs, redux, webrtc, reducers, simplewebrtc

I'm trying to integrate simpreWebRTC to my React-Redux project, but the library has their own redux store and the documentation says this:

"The provided `createStore` function makes a basic Redux
store useful for getting things started. If you want to
make your own, import `reducer` from '@andyet/simplewebrtc' and
be sure to assign it to `simplewebrtc` in the top level of
your state object."

I've tried several approaches but nothing works, any idea? what I'm missing here?
Thanks

This is the code that I have so far:

store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers/index'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
console.log(store.getState());
```

./reducers/index.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import {reducer as simplewertc} from '@andyet/simplewebrtc'
import liveRoomReducer from './liveRoomReducer'


export default combineReducers({simplewertc, liveRoomReducer});
```

./reducers/liveRoomReducer.js

```
const initialState = {    
    test : 'test' 
};

export default function liveRoomReducer(state=initialState, action) {    
    return state;
};
```

I'm logging the store state in the console and is showing simplewebrtc on it:

[image]

And still showing this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating your own store with thunk middleware and using `combineReducers` should do the trick:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {reducer as simplewebrtc} from '@andyet/simplewebrtc';
import reducer1 from 'path/to/your/reducer1';
import reducer2 from 'path/to/your/reducer2';

export default combineReducers({simplewebrtc, reducer1 , reducer2});
```

If that isn't working for you please provide what error is showing up if any and some example code of how you create your redux store and root reducer.

**Edit:** After seeing the updated question with code, we found the problem was in a typo when importing the reducer.

Comment: Already tried the combineReducer helper but still showing this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined in 
  function getConnectionState(state) {
 return state.simplewebrtc.api.connectionState;
}

Comment: Yeah, that looks like the simplewebrtc key is missing in state. If you get the state, is the key missing completely or is its value something like undefined/null? Also I would try logging the value of simplewebrtc reducer if its imported correctly.

Comment: I've updated the post with some code and pics, maybe the issue its more clear. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: you have `simplewertc` there instead of `simplewebrtc` :)

Comment: You got to be kidding me !!!!!! haha, its working now, thanks men, driving me crazy for a freaking errata, lol. Thanks again :) .